# How do I use the CSS3 multi-column module in a responsive design?

Tags: css

I want to use the CSS3 multi-column module but I need to figure something out.  When I change resolutions from small to large or vice versa,  the content of the columns fall apart.  So if I have 3 paragraphs in 3 columns,  the text spreads out and gets wonky instead of staying in its column when I resize.  How do I fix that?  Hope this makes sense and thank you.

Here is the link to my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Midtone/2RJ2J/

(please excuse the mess)

Comment: please set up a test case on jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
     body p {
     -webkit-column-count: 1;
     ...
     }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2RJ2J/1/)

For larger screen sizes, you could either put a `max-width` on the body, or use a similar technique but add more columns. However, even if someone has a big enough screen for it, I'm not sure reading something in 10 columns would be desirable.

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to put that query in. I set a max-width of 100% and it does not seem to work.  I want that text to stay put in the column while using the column module.  Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. *Every* screen has a `max-width` of 100% of itself. If you want the columns to not change, give it a discrete width.